# Selenium Wire Script: Status Code 64 Error - GeckoDriver and Firefox Version Mismatch on Debian 11

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am currently facing a challenging issue while attempting to run a Selenium Wire script on a Debian 11 server. The problem seems to revolve around the compatibility between the GeckoDriver (version 0.34) and the Firefox browser.

Here's a brief summary of the issue:

I have successfully installed GeckoDriver version 0.34 and added it to the system's path.
However, I am struggling to find the appropriate version of Firefox that is compatible with GeckoDriver 0.34.
When attempting to install Firefox through apt, I get version 115.6, which is not compatible with GeckoDriver 0.34.
Alternatively, installing Firefox from Snap provides version 120, but this version also fails to work with GeckoDriver 0.34.
The script consistently returns a "Status Code 64" error, indicating a mismatch between GeckoDriver and Firefox versions.

It does not work with normal selenium either

Script:

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
        )
```

I have searched error codes and tried installing firefox by various sources